# What is this comparator in the Arduino Uno Revision 3 doing?

Tags: arduino, pcb, comparator

I was looking into the schematic of the [Arduino Uno Rev3](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf) particularly the built-in on board LED (connected to pin 13) and was curious about what was happening.

Here you can see pin 5 of port B being connected to what appears to be a comparator which is in feedback with its own output.

[image]

[image]

Why not just connect it via a 1K resistor to yellow LED L?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would load the pin significantly if it was configured as an input.

Using half of a dual op-amp as a buffer is a reasonable design choice, when you need the other half elsewhere. Might not be optimal in all cases, but it's not unreasonable.

Another choice might be to use a 2N7002, with or without a series gate resistor and an LMV321 single op-amp for the other requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The LMV358 is an opamp, not a comparator, and that's called the "voltage follower" configuration. It's functioning as a buffer so that SCK isn't loaded directly by the LED.